# Owner dropdown not filtering Story cardboard

Tags: javascript, rally

I built a custom cardboard mashup to display all user stories that are in a "committed" iteration and beloning to the current project, or any child project. This much works well. I then added an Owner dropdown box (limited to Team Members only), to filter the stories on the cardboard. The resulting query value appears to be well formatted, yet no stories are displayed. I used an alert to copy the query string and paste it into a custom grid, which returned the expected list of stories.

Below is my code. Any assistance is appreciated.

```
        var rallyDataSource;
        var cardboard;
        var ownerDropdown;

        function refreshCardboard() {

            var cardboardConfig = {
                types: ["Defect", "HierarchicalRequirement"],
                attribute: "ScheduleState",
                fetch: "Name,FormattedID,Owner,ObjectID"
            };

            var query = rally.sdk.util.Query.and(['Iteration.Name != ""', 'Iteration.State = "Committed"']);

            if (ownerDropdown) {
                var ownerQuery = ownerDropdown.getValue();
                if (ownerQuery != 'ALL') {
                    query = '(' + query + ' AND Owner.Name = "' + ownerQuery + '")';
                }
            }

            cardboardConfig.query = query;
            if (!cardboard) {
                cardboard = new rally.sdk.ui.CardBoard(cardboardConfig, rallyDataSource);
                cardboard.display("cardboardDiv");
            } else {
                cardboard.refresh(cardboardConfig);
            }
        }

        function buildOwnerDropdown() {

            var teamMembersQuery = {
                key: "teamMembers",
                type: "User",
                fetch: "UserName,DisplayName",
                query: '(TeamMemberships = /project/__PROJECT_OID__)'
            };

            rallyDataSource.findAll(teamMembersQuery, function (results) {

                var ownerItems = [{ label: "-- ALL --", value: "ALL"}];
                rally.forEach(results.teamMembers, function (teamMember) {
                    ownerItems.push({ label: teamMember.DisplayName, value: teamMember.UserName });
                });

                ownerItems.sort();

                var ownerDropdownConfig = {
                    showLabel: true,
                    label: "Owner:",
                    items: ownerItems
                };

                ownerDropdown = new rally.sdk.ui.basic.Dropdown(ownerDropdownConfig);
                ownerDropdown.display("ownerDropdownDiv");
            });
        }

        function onLoad() {

            rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource(
                '__WORKSPACE_OID__',
                '__PROJECT_OID__',
                '__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__',
                '__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__');

            buildOwnerDropdown();

            refreshCardboard();
        }

        rally.addOnLoad(onLoad);

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="ownerDropdownDiv"></div>
    <input id="refreshButton" type="button" value="Filter" onclick="refreshCardboard()"/>
    <div id="cardboardDiv"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're really close to the mark - the problem lies here:

```
        var query = rally.sdk.util.Query.and(['Iteration.Name != ""', 'Iteration.State = "Committed"']);

        if (ownerDropdown) {
            var ownerQuery = ownerDropdown.getValue();
            if (ownerQuery != 'ALL') {
                query = '(' + query + ' AND Owner.Name = "' + ownerQuery + '")';
            }
        }
```

Rally's query syntax requires another nested set of parentheses when adding another AND condition. So when you concatenate on your third condition, you are ending up with a query clause that looks like this:

`((Iteration.Name != "") AND (Iteration.State = "Committed")) AND (Owner.Name = "user@company.com")`

When it needs to look like this:

`(((Iteration.Name != "") AND (Iteration.State = "Committed")) AND (Owner.Name = "user@company.com"))`

I slightly modified your refreshCardboard() function's query logic as follows, and your code seems to work now for me.

```
    ....        
    var queryArray = new Array('Iteration.Name != ""', 'Iteration.State = "Committed"');                                       
    var query;

    var selectedOwner = ownerDropdown.getValue();

    if (ownerDropdown) {
       if (selectedOwner != 'ALL') {
          var ownerClause = 'Owner.Name = "' + selectedOwner + '"';
          queryArray.push(ownerClause);
       }
    }

    query = rally.sdk.util.Query.and(queryArray);

    cardboardConfig.query = query;
    ....
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is always humbling to bang your head against a wall only to discover you were missing a parenthesis or comma or whatever...

Comment: Glad to help - we've all been there :)